# bluetooth adapters Cambridge Silicon Radio not to work

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth

this is one of the bluetooth adapters that pretend to be a 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) and appears not to work despite the numerous existing workarounds in the kernel.

```
1304.304169] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1304.454899] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice=25.20
[ 1304.454912] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1304.454917] usb 3-6: Product: CSR8510 A10
[ 1304.460191] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[ 1309.504660] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[ 1311.519834] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[ 1786.146342] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Local version failed (-32)

#~ uname -a
Linux leberman-HD631-Q87CRM 5.18.8-051808-generic #202206290850 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 29 08:59:08 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#~ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

#~ rfkill
 2: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

can you help me for connect this adapter?

---

DistroRelease: Ubuntu 22.04
Package: bluetooth 5.64-0ubuntu1
Uname: Linux 5.18.8-051808-generic x86_64